# Is it common to say "..., you forget?" instead of "..., did you forget?"

Tags: colloquial-language

Example sentence:

> It's your fault, (did) you forget?

A native English speaker said I should add the "did." But I think "you forget" is okay in casual speech. However, I'm not very sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to form questions in English using only question intonation (rising pitch at the end of the sentence) It is not as common in English as in some languages, and often implies that the speaker is expecting a particular answer.

> You've finished your homework already? (A child comes downstairs after spending 5 minutes doing homework. The parent is asking "did you finish already?" but is expressing doubt that the homework has been done properly)

In your example, "It's your fault, you forget?" with question intonation would mean "Did you forget that it was your fault, because you are acting as if it wasn't your fault."  But it could also be with falling intonation and could imply "You forget that it was your fault, and I want to remind you of the consequences"